# Java método static duda

Tags: java

Necesito usar la línea `r3=Racional.multiplicar(r1,r2);` de forma static en el siguiente código pero no sé como implementarla.

```
class Racional{
    int numerador;
    int denominador;

    Racional(int numerador, int denominador){
        this.numerador=numerador;
        this.denominador=denominador;
    }

    void multiplicar(Racional r1, Racional r2){
        this.numerador=r1.numerador*r2.numerador;
        this.denominador=r1.denominador*r2.denominador;
    }
}

class multiplicacion{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Racional r1=new Racional(3,4);
        Racional r2=new Racional(1,2);
        Racional r3=new Racional(1,1);
        r3.multiplicar(r1, r2);
        //Necesito implemtentar esta línea de forma 'static'.
        //r3=Racional.multiplicar(r1,r2);
        System.out.println("MUTIPLICACIÓN DE NÚMEROS RACIONALES");
        System.out.println("r1 vale: "+r1.numerador+"/"+r1.denominador);
        System.out.println("r2 vale: "+r2.numerador+"/"+r2.denominador);
        System.out.println("r3 vale: "+r3.numerador+"/"+r3.denominador);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es un método estático y que devuelva un objeto de tipo Racional:

```
public static Racional multiplicar(Racional r1, Racional 2){
    return new Racional(r1.numerador*r2.numerador, r1.denominador*r2.denominador);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona como quería.

Comment: Y de este modo mantienes los objetos de la clase Racional inmutables, como cualquier "wrapper" de Java